# Freemarker strip_text and strip_whitespace

Tags: freemarker

What is the use of freemarker strip_text and strip_whitespace in freemarker template language(FTL)?

I am starting the new project in fremarker and the freemarker documentation says that these values should be set to true for new projects.

[reference to Freemarker Documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_ftl.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same place it links to the description of whitespace stripping (http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html#dgui_misc_whitespace_stripping) and describes what's `strip_text` too. `strip_whitespace` is enabled by default, and `strip_text` shouldn't be enabled unless you know what you are doing, so you don't have to do anything.